# CSS content div to expand to the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, expand

Ok, i've tried LOTS of solutions offered in StackOverflow about this issue, but none of them have worked. I guess this is a tricky thing and needs a tricky solution.

From what I've seen, each problem is different with this 'occupying' the body thing, so I guess I'm here with a different one.

I really need help here, guys.

Here's my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Ff49Z/5/

And heres what I want: When the "wrapper" div does not fulfill the body, I want the div to expand to the bottom of it anyway. So, in the fiddle, what I'm trying to achieve is not a gray spot on my layout. As you can see, wrappers are 100% height (that is one common solution offered in SO for this problem) and that does not help.

It is this div that does not expand to fit the wrapper:

```css
div#middle {
    padding:10px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

BTW, when overscrolling, footer sticks and wrapper scrolls. That is the desired behaviour, and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I simply added:

```css
div#middlewrap {
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:60px;
}
```

and works as you asked. **EDIT: THIS IS WRONG - correct answer below**

---

I was about to give up when I decided to rewrite the css from scratch, and it came out simpler than I expected. I simplified your CSS to the bones and added some cool `overflow-y:auto;` to the middle wrapper plus some sweet `position:fixed;` to the header and the footer.  Then I adjusted the padding to the `#middle` content div and added a `height:100%;` to the body and html(so that every child of body can be successfully set to `height:100%;`) and that's what came out:

```css
body, html {
    margin:0;
    height:100%;
}
div#headerwrap, div#footerwrap {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
div#headerwrap {
    top: 0;
    height:64px;
    background-color: red;
}
div#middlewrap {
    height:100%;
    overflow-y:auto;
    background-color: blue;
}
div#middle {
    padding-top:70px;
    padding-bottom:35px;
}
div#footerwrap {
    bottom: 0;
    height:32px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

That's all the CSS you need. Pretty cool uh?
[**HERE IS THE FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ff49Z/11/)
Note: I respected your syntax, which is also correct, but it's not necessary to write DIV before every #ID in your css. Deleting those selectors will dramatically decrease your css file weight in bigger projects.
Cheers.

Comment: first off, thank you for the answer, but it does not work as I asked, as a scrollbar appears when not needed. I just want the div to reach the bottom of the page (exactly the bottom, I guess, no more no less) when the content does not fullfill the container, but the scrollbar should appear only when needed (that worked on my firs fiddle). I will keep trying, thanks.

Comment: you just have to adjust/delete the padding properties to avoid the overscroll. if it helped you please consider to accept my answer as correct. cheers.

Comment: here you go, just tweaked some z-index property and deleted all margin/padding on wrappers. you can manage them by inner divs. cheers. http://jsfiddle.net/Ff49Z/10/

Comment: this breaks my sticky header off the first fiddle. when content overscrolls, the scroll overrides the header. padding does not solve this issue :(

Comment: ok, we posted at the same second. on the last solution, is the overscrolling that does not work. When the content overscrolls, the wrapper does not grow with it.

Comment: ok here you go for real now, i edited my answer with the right code.

Comment: Thank you so much. As a final note, it is not my code, as I'm not a web designer and I suck at css, I'm just helping a friend here.

Answer (score 1):

Make all parent elements as `height:100%`:

```css
body, html, body>div#middlewrap {
    height: 100%;
}
div#middle {
    min-height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Impossible solely with CSS. Need javascript involved. Take the client height - (header + footer) = min height for the content

Using % height doesn't work because the parent doesn't have a height defined.

Comment: thank you, I'm trying to keep it simple, but I will look into using JS if no CSS solution work.